Unable to bind MaxWidth on RadGridView to property in WPF Xaml
I'm unable to set the MaxWidth of a Telerik child RadGridView without hardcoding the value.  Here's what I'm trying to do: if the screen width resolution is less than 1400 then set the width of the grid to one value, else set it to another.  Add a horizontal scrollbar to the grid.
I tried setting the main Window width to SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth but that doesn't want to work for this radgrid.
Setting the MaxWidth to SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth does not achieve the width desired.
So now I'm trying to bind MaxWidth to a property.
Here's the property setup:
Public Class MaxWidthComputation

Public Sub New()
    maxWidth = 0
End Sub

Private _maxWidth As Integer
Public Property maxWidth As Integer
    Get
        Return _maxWidth
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _maxWidth = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
Here's the coding to set the property value:
   Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Try
        Dim oScreenWidth As New MaxWidthComputation
        If Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width < 1400 Then
            oScreenWidth.maxWidth = 1000
        Else
            oScreenWidth.maxWidth = 1900
        End If

Here's the xaml:
                <telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dgOrdersForProjects"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            MaxHeight="400"
                            MaxWidth="{Binding maxWidth}"

What do I need to change to get this to work as expected?
Thanks.

Does it work as expected if you set it to a hardcoded value? Try to change the type of the source property to Double.

The maxWidth property must fire a change notification. This means the MaxWidthComputation class must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and the property setter must fire the PropertyChanged event. In addition, to make MaxWidth="{Binding maxWidth}" work, an instance of MaxWidthComputation must be assigned to the DataContext property of the view. See Data Binding Overview.
